# How to ignore trailing slash in marionette routes?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I am defining routes in Marionettejs as follows:

```
var Mn = require('backbone.marionette');

var Router = Mn.AppRouter.extend({
    routes: {
        '': 'default',
        'login': 'login',     // http://localhost:8080/#/login
        'signup': 'signup'    // http://localhost:8080/#/signup
    }, 
    initialize: function () {
        var initData = this.getOption('keyInOptions');
    },
    // below are route functions
    default: function () {
        console.log('this is default route');
    }, 
    login: function () {
        console.log('this is login route');
    },
    signup: function () {
        console.log('this is signup route');
    }
});

module.exports = Router;
```

Then in the browser:

> http://localhost:8080/#/login

successfully triggers the login route, but

> http://localhost:8080/#/login/

(add one forward slash at the end) will not trigger login route function. I know I can define another route entry:

```
...
'login': 'login',
'login/': 'login',
...
```

to solve this problem, but this solution will double the entries in router definition. Is there a better way to trigger the same route handler for `login` and `login/` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried surrounding the trailing slash with parentheses?  Like the following:

```
routes: {
    'login(/)': 'login'
}
```

From the backbone [documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Router):

> Part of a route can be made optional by surrounding it in parentheses
>   (/:optional).